# Do the sanity loss cap rules apply to seeing dead bodies?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-7e, sanity

Do the sanity loss cap rules apply to seeing corpses?

The rules for sanity loss state that once an investigator have suffered the maximum sanity loss for seeing a mythos creature, any further loss is negated. For instance, if they see a ghoul (sanity loss 1/1d6) and lose 4 points, any more ghouls encountered can only result in 2 more points of sanity loss. Once that max loss is reached, the investigator will suffer no more loss from seeing ghouls.

So, does the same cap apply for other sanity loss sources? If they see one dead body and take the max loss of 3 points, then later come upon a dump-truck full of corpses will they suffer more sanity loss? Or do they build up the same sanity loss resistance described for mythos creatures?

Comment: I cant remember seeing any rules stating a "cap". Can you tell me under which section you found them?

Comment: @Opaldes Chapter 8: Sanity under the heading "Getting used to the Awfulness"

Comment: I would think that a dump-truck full of corpses would be *worse* than finding a single corpse.

Comment: @KieranMullen The ‘dump truck of corpses’ is different to the ‘Getting used to the awfulness’ rule, which handles repeat exposure over time, not ‘loads all at once’. However, there are rules in place for encountering multiples of the same thing as a single event; I don’t have the rules in front of me, I seem to recall that you roll SAN loss for each and take the highest roll as the total for the group. So, if you encounter 9 deep ones you roll 9d6 and take the highest of those 9 rolls as the SAN loss for that whole world encounter. I mean, I suppose it _might_ only be a 5…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## RAW: No

As you have quoted, the rules as written (ch.8, "Getting used to the Awfulness") state that sanity loss caused *by the same type of Mythos Creature* gets capped, not *by the same type of source*.

So any source of SAN loss that is not specifically a Mythos Creature can, in theory, inflict an ever increasing amount of insanity to an investigator.

## RAI: Probably yes

While this is obviously pure speculation on my part, it seems sensible to read this section as pertaining to sanity loss incurred by any set of similar sources - after all, it seems silly that a person could get used to seeing a walking corpse, but every new inanimate corpse one encounters is just as shocking as the first.